# Strange behavior of the web service which generates random vectors

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, silverlight, random

Can somebody explain my program's strange behaviour?

I have created a web service. It contains a method that generates a set of three-dimensional random vectors which have positive coordinates with a sum equal to 1. In order to generate these vectors I use class `RandomNess` from [here](http://greenash.net.au/media/uploads/files/randfixedsum.cs_.txt). My code is the following:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1
{
    [OperationContract]
    public void GenerateRandomVectors()
    {
        RandomNess.RandomNess rand = new RandomNess.RandomNess();
        var vector = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {      
            //The first parameter of RandFixedSum is dimension of vector;
            //The second parameter is a required sum of elements;
            //The third and the fourth parameters are bounds for elements; 
            vector = rand.RandFixedSum(3, 1, 0, 1); 

            //Writing obtained vector to a file;
            ...
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I call the service from a  Silverlight application with the following code:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client web;
web = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
web.GenerateRandomVectorsAsync();
```

When I visualise the result I see that the obtained points fill only a part of standard simplex. So, the method gives the wrong result (see picture [here](http://s29.postimg.org/7ccg15mjb/123.jpg)).

BUT(!) if I call the method `RandFixedSum(...)` directly from the Silverlight application (not from web service) or from a Windows Forms application I obtain absolutely correct distribution (points fill all surface of standard simplex).

What is wrong with my web service? Why does it give the wrong results?

Comment: Have you looked at the file to verify it has the values expected?  What does your code look like that writes the file?

Comment: Another thought: I see you're calling an `Async` web method.  Is it possible that the file hasn't finished writing when your Silverlight code reads it?

Comment: Unfortunately file writing is absolutley correct. The file contains all 1000 vectors when I read it.

Comment: ... Then the async issue?

Comment: Writing the file is completely finished when I read it (it contains all 1000 records). May be the problem in async calling, but what is this problem? Why does asyncronous calling give the wrong results?

Comment: My thought was that async could allow you to read the file _before it was finished writing_, which would give undesired results.  I don't know if that's the case.  Try going without async to see if it works differently.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't call methods of web service without async because my client is Silverlight application.

Comment: The problem may be in your Silverlight code.

Comment: No, I can guarantee that application which reads and visualizes points works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to web.GenerateRandomVectorsCompleted before making a call to web.GenerateRandomVectorsAsync() and start parsing the data file that was created by your web service in the event handler.

Comment: I solved my problem! I found out that standard function `list.Sort(...)` works incorrectly when it is called from Web Service (of course, it is very strange). So, I wrote this function manually and the problem dissapeared.